# How to bind remote socket address in DatagramSocket

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How to Set Remote Machine address in the UDP socket, That should be returned while the receiver getting the socket address?

My Code:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[10],10);

packet.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostName));

packet.setPort(portNum);

byte[] data = message.getBytes();

packet.setData(data);

packet.setLength(data.length);

socket.send(packet);
socket.close();
```

But this create a socket with my local address, receiver receives my address instead of that remote host address.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: I just can't understand what you're saying. Is it just me?

Comment: @iccthedral I think what is going on (and I put an answer for this) is the user   wants to make a request and have the result go to a remote machine instead of his local machine.  Problem is, the remote machine does not make the connection, his local does so all resulted transmissions are being sent back to him instead of the remote machine.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The only address you can bind a socket to is a local address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are the one making the request, so your address will be the one that gets submitted for the response.  If you are wanting the remote machine to receive the response, the UDP connection (Datagram Socket Connection) must be established by the remote machine and not your own.

Comment: Is there any possibility to satisfy my requirement?

Comment: You would have to have your program on the remote machine, Remote into the machine from your local machine and run the program from your Remote Machine.  This makes your connection between your remote machine and your server, and a separate connection between your local machine and your remote machine.